# Java 8 instead of simple java

Tags: java, java-stream

I am playing with java streams. Currently, I want to compare 2 lists based on another list.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Sample {


List <String> text = Stream.of("a","b","c").collect(Collectors.toList());
List <String> text1 = Stream.of("1","2","3").collect(Collectors.toList());
List <String> text2= Stream.of("a","b","c").collect(Collectors.toList());

public void iter(){
    for (int i =0; i<text1.size(); i++){
        if(text.get(i).equals(text2.get(i))){System.out.println("True");}
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sample s = new Sample();
    s.iter();       

}
}
```

My questions, if you can show me how can I use java stream instead of that "for". Thank You.

Comment: `for (int i =0; i<text1.size(); i++)` is a misuse. might get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` if size is not same

Comment: The only reason of text1 list existance is to get the size? or i'm wrong? Why not comparing text and text2 directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out,

```
IntStream.range(0, text1.size()).filter(i -> text.get(i).equals(text2.get(i)))
        .forEach(ignored -> System.out.println("True"));
```

Comment: This is not comparing streams.  It is comparing lists using a stream.  And you may as well do that using `List::equals`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to check if elements are present in another `List` you can just use `text.containsAll(text2)`. You can use `equals` if the order is same in both list or you can just use `Set`.

If you want to use stream then:

```
text.forEach(x -> System.out.println(text2.contains(x)));
```